# Can I make a table and insert variables into the rows?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am building an automated email system that will send an email when a specific columns is edited based on another columns value being true. Right now I have it so that the output if that column is updated will tell me some other values in that row on different columns.

I have a co-worker who has a similar working project in HTML where the variables are called into a daily digest form. However, I can't duplicate it and get it to work for some reason. I also tried several methods I found on here in java script such as arrayToDataTable. And building it in HTML in the HTML body. But when I try those the output is just the word of the variable but not the variable itself.

```
function sendNotification(e){ 

  var ss = e.source.getSheetByName('Datasheet'); 
  var cell = e.range.getA1Notation(); 
  var row = e.range.getRow(); 
  var col = e.range.getColumn(); 
  var cellvalue = e.range.getValue(); 
  var subject = 'SUBJECT: '+ ss.getSheetName(); 
  var name = ss.getRange(row, 9).getValue(); 
  var control = ss.getRange(row, 2).getValue();
  var owner = ss.getRange(row, 8).getValue();  
  var key = ss.getRange(row, 3).getValue();


  if (name === 'NAME' && (col === 2 || col === 3 || col === 23 || col === 
24 || col === 31 || col === 32) === true) {  




   MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: "EMAIL",
      subject: subject,
      htmlBody:( <table> <tr> <th>Control ID</th> <th>  Control Owner  
</th> <th>  Updated Cell  </th>  </tr> <tr> <td>  control  </td> <td>  
owner  </td> <td>  cellvalue  </td> </tr> </table> + 


      "<br><br>The following cell has been updated: <br><br>"+
      "<font size=\"2.5\" color=\"black\"><b> CONTROL ID: </b></font>" + 
control + "<br>" +
      "<font size=\"2.5\" color=\"black\"><b> OWNER: </b></font>" + owner 
+ "<br>" + 
      "<font size=\"2.5\" color=\"black\"><b> UPDATED CELL: </b></font>" + 
cellvalue + "<br>" + 
      "<font size=\"2.5\" color=\"black\"><b> SIGNIFICANCE: </font>" + key 
+ "</b><br>" + 
      "<br><br>Thank you. <br><br><br><br>"
    )
    })
  }
}
```

I want the output instead of reading line by line be transferred into an output table. Just to clean it up and make it look nice and professional. I feel like this should be possible but I can't get it working. After I get this table working I am going to work on storing a full 24 hours worth of updates and inputting it into the table as a daily digest output.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your html should be a string.

Comment: How would I make it a string? I am new to Google-apps-script.

Comment: @Hippo Google Apps Script is mostly an implementation of Ecmascript (Javascript's standard), so basic programming questions will be best answered by [a Javascript tutorial](https://javascript.info/string) (note that GAS doesn't generally support ES6 features, so [template literals won't work](https://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_overviews.html#overview-entry-strings)). For more information, the [MDN documentation on strings in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)

Comment: Hey @Altigraph, that is good to know! I initially tried to get javascript tutorials to work and was curious why I was missing actions and other commands. I tried the GAS API but even the commands available on there don't seem to all work or show up for me. For example, when I tried to call a table from appendTable() or arrayToDataTable() neither commands worked. I will take a look at the links you posted above for more information on what I am doing.

Comment: Put quotes around it.

Comment: @Hippo Keep in mind that the API documentation you are looking at may be for other Google APIs, which may or may not be able to be [used within Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced), and which would be used differently than the [built-in Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/) provided by Apps Script. Make sure that what you're reading is for Apps Script. Apart from that and ES6, be careful to note any libraries that tutorials may use as well.